# List of objects not getting updated using java web services

Tags: java, rest

I am building a simple web app, using `rest` services in java . I want to update a list of objects of type `Person`. Here is my code so far:

```java
public class Provider {

   private final PersonList pl = new PersonList();

   public Provider() {
      final List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
      PersonList.add( new Person( "1", "firstName1", "secondName1", "age1"));
      PersonList.add( new Person( "2", "firstName2", "secondName2", "age2"));
      PersonList.add( new Person( "3", "firstName3", "secondName3", "age3"));
      PersonList.add( new Person( "4", "firstName4", "secondName4", "age4"));
      PersonList.add( new Person( "5", "firstName5", "secondName5", "age5"));

      this.pl.setPersonList( PersonList );
   }


   public PersonList getPersons() {
      return this.pl;
   }


   public Person getPerson( final String id ) {
      return this.pl.getPerson( id );
   }


   public List<Person> updatePerson( final String id, final Person Person ) {
      return this.pl.updatePerson( id, Person );
   }

}

public class PersonList {

   private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();


   public List<Person> getPersonList() {
      return this.personList;
   }


   public void setPersonList(List<Person> PersonList ) {
      this.personList = personList;
   }


   public int getPersonIndex(Person person) {
      int index = -1;

      for ( int i = 0; i < this.PersonList.size(); i++ ) {
         if (this.personList.get(i).getId().equals(person.getId()))
            index = i;
      }

      return index;
   }


   public Person getPerson(String id )
   {
      Person person = new Person();
      for (Person p : this.personList ) {
         if ( p.getId().equals( id ) )
            return p;
      }
      return person;
   }


   public List<Person> updatePerson(String id, Person p) {
      final Person person = this.getPerson( id );
      final int personIndex = this.getPersonIndex( person );

      person.setFirstName(p.getFirstName());
      person.setSecondName(p.getSecondName());
      person.setAge(p.getAge());

      this.personList.set( personIndex, person );

      return this.personList;
   }

}
```

And the request in the service:

```java
   @PUT
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/update/{id}")
   public Response updatePerson( @PathParam("id") String id, Person p ) {
      Person p = this.provider.getPerson( id );
      if ( p.getd() != null ) {
         Person person = new Person( id, p.getFirstName(), f.getSecondName(), p.getAge());
         return Response.ok( this.provider.updatePerson(id, person), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).build();
      }

      return Response.ok( "Person doesn't exist", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).build();
   }
```

My problem is that when I do the update it returns the list updated with the new values, but when I do again a getAll for the list I get back the old list.

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your code a bit to remove the `PersonList` class, which I think is unnecessary since much of that functionality is covered by `Map`s. In this case I'm using a `LinkedHashMap` which has a predictable order.

```java
public class Provider {

    private final Map<String, Person> mapOfPersons;

    public Provider() {
        this.mapOfPersons = new LinkedHashMap<String, Person>();

        for (int id = 1; id <= 5; id++) {
            final String idString = Integer.toString(id);
            mapOfPersons.put(idString, new Person(idString, "firstName" + id, "secondName" + id, "age" + id));
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Person> getMapOfPersons() {
        return mapOfPersons;
    }

    // Since we're operating directly on the person that is in the map you don't need to upate the map.
    public Map<String, Person> updatePerson(String id, Person p) {
        final Person person = this.mapOfPersons.get(id);

        person.setFirstName(p.getFirstName());
        person.setSecondName(p.getSecondName());
        person.setAge(p.getAge());

        return this.mapOfPersons;
    }

    // Probably you'll never use this.
    public int getPersonIndex(Person person) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(mapOfPersons.keySet()).indexOf(person.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should review your code to simplify it and eliminate certain bogus issues, as:

- Instantiating unused variables (`personList` in `Provider` constructor).
- Returning a dummy object when the identifier is not found (`getPerson`).
- And of corse, you'd better save yourself unnecesary abstractions as PersonList where a Map would be enough (as @Craig sensitively suggests).

But I think that the root cause is this method:

```
   public void setPersonList(List<Person> PersonList ) {
      this.personList = personList;
   }
```

Notice that it does nothing.

A good practice to avoid this kind of mistakes is to take care of nomenclature:

- Class names should be named starting with uppercase (`PersonList`).
- Variable names should be named starting with lowercase (`personList`).